# ReactJS when Fetch POST, and use then function to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

In my ReactJS project, I use fetch the do the async processing, and after fetch the data,

I want to setState to change my local state. But I get the error return.

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Fetch function code:

```
AddDeal(deal){
fetch('shops/1/deals',{
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(deal),
      headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    }).then(response => {
         response.json().then(data =>{
           this.setState({deals: data}); // and use this.props.dispatch I get `props` of undefined 
         })
      })
}
```

I have watched the other question like mine [React.js: loading JSON data with Fetch API and props from object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497711/react-js-loading-json-data-with-fetch-api-and-props-from-object-array)

So how can I fix it?

Comment: from where you are calling `AddDeal` method?

Comment: Do you bind `AddDeal`?

Comment: have you tried binding `this` to `AddDeal()`? Would be good to include how you execute `AddDeal()`

Comment: @MayankShukla My React Component, this method is running when I submit the form

Comment: @edgaromar90 I haven't `bind.this.AddDeal()`. Let me try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `fetch()`, the value of `this` will be the response, not the class. You can save the value of `this` by assigning it to a variable, usually called `self`.

```
AddDeal(deal){
  const self = this;
  fetch('shops/1/deals',{
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(deal),
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  }).then(response => {
    response.json().then(data =>{
      self.setState({deals: data});
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Better declare `AddDeal` like so :

`AddDeal = (deal) => {...}`

Comment: So Is it any association for `bind(this)` ? I tried to follow the other answer to `bind(this)` the `AddDeal` function, but it since did not work.

Comment: Two separate issues. For this to work in React, you need to bind the function to the class or use arrow functions. Additionally, fetch overrides this as I explained. `this` can be quite confusing in JS

Answer (score 1):

This will probably solve your issue:

```
AddDeal = (deal) => {
  fetch('shops/1/deals',{
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(deal),
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  }).then(response => {
    response.json().then(data =>{
      this.setState({deals: data});
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, this is the right approach

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

   ..............
   ..............
   ..............

    this.AddDeal = this.AddDeal.bind(this)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to use Axios rather than using fetch, because axios has more great features as compared to Fetch. 
You can read about the great features of Axios from here [Link](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/fetch-vs-axios-js-for-making-http-requests-2b261cdd3af5).